# Column @Id is resetting back to the starting number after upgrading hibernate version from 5.0.3.Final to 5.4.24.Final

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a java project to uses hibernate.
I have my base enrty that all my other entires are extended to:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntry {
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "itpGenerator")
    @TableGenerator(name = "itpGenerator",
            // the first 999 entries are saved for items that come with the system
            initialValue = 1000,
            allocationSize = 100
    )
    @Column(name="ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

example for such entry that extended to the base:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AD_ENDPOINTS")
public class ActiveDirectoryEndpointEntry extends BaseEntry {
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "FRIENDLY_NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

so let's say that before the upgrade, I entered 2 entries for ActiveDirectoryEndpointEntry and they were kept in the database with id 1001 and 1002.

after I upgraded the hibernate version to 5.4.24.Final and tried to enter a new entry for ActiveDirectoryEndpointEntry, I get an error:

```
 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ad_endpoints_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(1001) already exists.
```

meaning the id was reset back to the staring number.
How can I prevent the id from going back to the starting number and continue the sequence that started before the upgrade?